# how to configure pixi resolution in palm emulator

Tags: webos

I am trying to configure the pixi resolution in palm emulator by 
http://developer.palm.com/index.php?opt ... Resolution

the above site instructions when i restart emulator it is showing error

```
Failed to start the virtual machine Palm Emulator(1.2.0.33).
Unknown error creating VM 
(VERR_VGA_INVALID_CUSTOM_MODE).
```

Details

```
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {0a51994b-cbc6-4686-94eb-d4e4023280e2}
```

Comment: that is the only problem i am facing when i trying to start the emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it. i downloaded latest sdk and emulator .when i start emulator itself it is asking resoltion my problem is solved